# How can I read a file from a path relative of my Main class in Java?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, java-io

On the same directory of my **Main.java** file, I have a package/folder named **database**, and inside the database package I have a file named **Data.txt**.

This is my code of **Main.java**, but it is throwing this error:

> java: exception java.io.FileNotFoundException

How can I get the file from a relative file? I'm used to web development, and usually something with a . dot like **"./folder/file.txt"** works.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            readFile();

        }

        public static void readFile() {

            File file = new File("./database/Data.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            try {

                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    int i = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
                scanner.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: You're not executing Main.java. You're executing Main.class, which is in a different folder.

Comment: Show us your folder structure. Otherwise we can just guess.

Comment: I have written in the question...

Comment: Is your Java file in some kind of `src` folder and your `database` folder also? If so, move it one out. Where is the `class` file located? You should start by printing where you currently at when you don't change the path: `System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());`. What does it list? Is it where you believed it would be?

Comment: Also nowadays files aren't read by `File` anymore. Use **NIO** revolving around `Files`, `Paths` and `Path`. Reading is done by using `Files#lines` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing FileNotFoundException class. also, scanner statement throws the exception which should inside try. Solution is as below.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        readFile();

    }

    public static void readFile() {

        File file = new File("database/Data.txt");

        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                int i = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            scanner.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Only check if those content can read using scanner or not. Content having int properly. otherwise it will throw java.util.InputMismatchException.

Comment: what is data in Data.txt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159436/discussion-between-devram-kandhare-and-diogo-capela).

Comment: Still not working...

java.io.FileNotFoundException: database/Data.txt (No such file or directory)

Comment: you might using window in this case use double slash like - database//Data.txt

Comment: what is your package name?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on a mac or windows system.
I am on windows and ".\database\Data.txt" would most probably work depending on where the file is in your file structure.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32291179)